# How to use AngularJS within Google Apps Script

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script

Is it possible to use Angular.js as part of a web app served using HtmlService in Google Apps Script?

I also changed the **`Code.gs`** file as mentioned in below link.
[How can I use Angular.js in a Google Apps Script served HTML site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737033/how-can-i-use-angular-js-in-a-google-apps-script-served-html-site)

But not getting success.

**Source Code :**

**`Code.gs`**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent()
}
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <?!= include('Javascript'); ?>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`Javascript.html`**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.heading = 'Welcome';
  $scope.message = 'Please enjoy this helpful script';
});
</script>
```

**Output i am getting in console :**

> Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-modals',
> 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' are invalid sandbox flags. dev:14
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined VM4501:2 
> Uncaught
> object

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the angular.js include script statement into the **head** section. It needs to be setup before the remaining javascript file is included. It works then. check it here:
[GAS-angularJS](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxj2FID2RI2QvdrwdujLm9FUpP5YIE3zjv5CGC3zeBX3ch7M1M/exec)